# NodeJS and Cassandra CQL Can not Execute

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to simple SELECT Query on the Cassandra via NodeJS.

I have a keyspace name is **test** and I have one table name is **Calisanlar**

When I try to execute this query in the **DevCenter**

```
select * from test.Calisanlar;
```

Error comes up. So when I tried to this:

```
select * from test."Calisanlar";
```

Query is working successfuly.

And I want to do this in the NodeJS. Here is my NodeJS Code:

```
var cql = require('node-cassandra-cql');
var client = new cql.Client({hosts: ['192.168.2.119'], keyspace: 'test', username: 'cassandra', password: 'cassandra'});
client.execute('SELECT * FROM test."Calisanlar";',
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.log('execute failed');
    else console.log('got user profile with email ' + result.rows[0]);
  }
); 
client.on('log', function(level, message) {
  console.log('log event: %s -- %j', level, message);
});
```

Output:

```
log event: info -- "Opened connection #0"
log event: info -- "Checking next connection"
log event: info -- "connection #0 acquired, executing: SELECT * FROM test.\"Calisanlar\";"
execute failed
```

So problem is I think caused from escaping term. Because "Calisanlar" seems **\"Calisanlar\"**
I tried the escape terms in Javascript and did not effect. And tried to escapint modules. Nothing change.

How can I handle this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what is value of err?

Comment: basic syntax error of cql because it is going like \"Calisanlar\" because of I could not handle the escaping terms. It should be only "Calisanlar".

Comment: instead of execute failed you can log err. That might be helpful

Comment: Hello, failing is relation with Javascript Escapint Terms. But why? Because in the Cassandra, if you do not use the double quotes but you have an uppercased table name, Cassandra requires it for detecting the upper case  tables. I solved this problem but just I re-generate the table and this time name contains only lowercases. But if I have any uppercase char in the future? I'm wondering what will be happen? You can see the main fail on the Output section. Just it sends wrong query to the database and database returns error.